# How to reuse UIView like UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, reusability

I have an app that has many instances of the same UIView. Is their a way to reuse a UIView like you can with UITableViewCell? Similar to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or not, this may differ the answer...

Comment: @lehn0058 you should look at this Let's Build UITableView https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-02-22-lets-build-uitableview.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you watch session **104** of WWDC'**2010** called "Designing Apps with ScrollViews" that explains the reuse mechanism (IIRC).

You can also look at the source of [`OHGridView`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHGridView) in which I implemented this technique: look at the 2nd `layoutSubviews` method in [OHGridView.m](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHGridView/blob/master/OHGridView/OHGridView.m) where I add unused `UIViews` in an `NSMutableSet` I called `recyclePool`, and then dequeue some `UIViews` from this `recyclePool` when I need one.

Comment: I think this is what I am lookin for. So the NSMutableSet is the key here. If i add the distinct instances of UIView to the set, then retrieving a UIView from it would give me a reference to a view that has not been modified. I guess I am getting confused because I keep thinking that requesting the same object from a set and then modifying that object would modify the object in the set. So what you are saying is that this is not the case, correct?

Comment: Of course this is the case. You will manipulate the very same object in the set or outside of it, this will be the same reference. If you modify it, the one in the set will be modified too, because this is the same object. **But** that's exactly how `UITableView` and their cells works too: when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, you get an `UITableViewCell` that has already been used before and still has values affected to it the last time you used it. That's why you reset all the values (`textLabel.text` etc) each time you dequeue a cell to override the previous ones.

Comment: Actually I am not sure of what you want to achieve here and if you use the right vocabulari: do you actually want to **reuse** a view, so that it sometimes is visible on screen, then disappear but you then later need this view to display it elsewhere, etc, so you will put this view aside when you remove it from the original view, and pick it later to display it on a different view? Or do you want multiple instances of a view that has the same look each time, and use all the instances at the same time? Meaning you need to create multiple views that look the same to be displayed at the same time

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't totally clear. I want to use it like a table view that has the same type of cell in each row, but only needs to alloc the object once even if I use 100 rows all with different data. I think the NSMutableSet is what I want, but I just don't see how the UI will display the correct values in I change them when referencing the same object. It's almost like I need to render it and then change the values...

Comment: Well that's exactly the same way an UITableView works then: if at most say 6 cells are visible at all times, it will allocate 6 different cells, so you will have 6 different instances (and not only one, in case it was not clear). Each time a cell goes out of scope and disappear from the screen, it is removed from its superview (a.k.a the tableview) and put in the "recycle pool" of the tableview. Each time you need a cell, you first ask the tableview if it has a cell in its "recycle pool". […]

Comment: […] If not, you allocate a new one, **but** if you get a recycle cell, then you will have a cell that has previously been used and kept its old values, so you will set the values (like `textLabel.text` and so one) again after dequeuing the cell to override the previous values. The UI will always display the right values because you change the values then add the view to the screen, **and you only put views in the recycle pool** to be reused later **if they are not displayed on screen anymore**. Of course, you don't recycle views that are currently used/displayed on screen!

Comment: (And once again you should really watch those WWDC videos talking about scroll views and recycling, all I explain here is detailed in the videos with examples and code)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NSCache to cache the UIView instances you need to cache. NSCache differs from NSDictionary because it does not copy the key to obtain the value, and it allows some good mechanism to deal with memory. Check [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and see if it works for you. I have used this very recently to cache UIPinAnnotationView objects.

Comment: That would work for storing the views, but their are only 3 types, used used over many times. I am wondering more about how to reuse the views so I don't need to reconstruct them.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code demonstrates basic pool that dequeue a view if it is not in any hierarchy. For complex use cases, you should need identifiers, lock, ...

Take a look at my gist [FTGViewPool](https://gist.github.com/onmyway133/510deac69c6f71f1b8b0)

```
@interface FTGViewPool ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *views;
@property (nonatomic, assign) Class viewClass;

@end

@implementation FTGViewPool

- (instancetype)initWithViewClass:(Class)kClass {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _views = [NSMutableArray array];
        _viewClass = kClass;
    }

    return self;
}

- (UIView *)dequeueView {
    // Find the first view that is not in any hierarchy
    for (UIView *view in self.views) {
        if (!view.superview) {
            return view;
        }
    }

    // Else create new view
    UIView *view = [[self.viewClass alloc] init];
    [self.views addObject:view];
    return view;
}
```